# How to get Authorization Code from Google Play Services without adding account to device?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

On my app, I am able to get **Authorisation Code** using google play services. The app shows this type of screen to select an account::

[image: Account Selection Popup]
For a new account, user can select 'Add account' and enter the email and password. This way, I get the Authorisation code. But I just need the code to be passed to server, I don't want the account to be added to user's device.

Please help me with this or suggest alternatives so I can get authorisation code without adding an account to the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the authorization code for Google Play Developer API, I think you can use this:

1. Go to [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/?code=4/ExZ08HrxZLTe28x3wI2ZDi-WRb41OQk-3kPUB4q0iXc#). Scroll down to Google Play Developer API v2.
2. Choose `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher` permission and click Authorize APIs. Allow permission.
3. You'll move to Step 2. Here you'll see the **authorization code**. You have the option to exchange them for tokens.

If this is not what you're looking for, then there is no alternative to your problem except to login the new account and remove from the device afterwards.